# Erro no pacote ‘topicmodels’

Tags: r

Estou utilizando o RStudio para fazer meus scritps. Tento instalar um pacote chamado `topicmodels` através do comando

```
install.packages("topicmodels")
```

Entretanto, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘tm’ is not available for package ‘topicmodels’.
```

Versão do RStudio: Version 1.1.456.
Sistema Operacional: Ubuntu 16.04

Como eu resolveria isso?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Eu tentei instalar este pacote aqui na minha máquina e deu tudo certo. Eu uso o `R 3.5.1`. Talvez seja a versão do `R` na tua máquina que esteja desatualizada. Por favor, rode o comando `sessionInfo()`, copie o resultado e edite a sua pergunta com ele. Isto nos ajudará a tentar resolver o teu problema.

Answer (score 2):

No R, faça:

```
install.packages('tm')
install.packages('topicmodels')
```

Se isso não der certo, abra o terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) e execute:

```
sudo apt-get install gsl-bin libgsl2
```

e depois

```
sudo apt-get install gsl-bin libgsl-dev
```

digite `Y` quando for solicitado.

Após, vá ao R e:

```
install.packages('topicmodels')
```

Tentei aqui e funcionou.

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação. Seui sua dica, mas deu este erro: :(                      ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’
* removing ‘/home/adriano/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/xml2’
ERROR: dependency ‘xml2’ is not available for package ‘tm’
* removing ‘/home/adriano/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/tm’
ERROR: dependency ‘tm’ is not available for package ‘topicmodels’
* removing ‘/home/adriano/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/topicmodels’
...
3: In install.packages("topicmodels") :
  installation of package ‘topicmodels’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Você executou os dois códigos no terminal?

Comment: Segui seus passos. Deu erro! Apareceu o mesmo erro:                                             Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
    Couldn't connect to server

Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :

ERROR: dependency ‘xml2’ is not available for 
Warning message:
In install.packages("tm") :
  installation of package ‘tm’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Execute esta ação no R: `install.packages('xml2')`. Depois, execute tudo de novo.

Comment: Deu certo, amigo!